# How to bifurcate data in table according to a particular value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the table I am receiving data from the db, and all the marks have a particular value A or B. According to the value I need to separate the data , if the mark has value A it should be stored under the A and if mark has the value B it should be stored under B. I am not sure how to write the jquery for this problem. I have attached a fiddle along with the post. Showing only the html and the required format of the table.

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td>Marks</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>75</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>Required Table format
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzzp5/

Comment: can't you split the data on the server? that's a classic use case for server-side table rendering that's slightly more complex than what you already have.

Comment: yeah , but is it possible to do it in the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <table style="width:300px" id="marksId">
    <tr>
        <td>Marks</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>75</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>
Required Table format

    <table style="width:300px" id="reqtable">
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
```

Your script goes here

```
  $(function(){
        var data={'a':[],'b':[]};
        $('#marksId tr').each(function(index,tr){
            if($(tr).find('td').eq(1).text()=='a'){

                    data.a.push($(tr).find('td').eq(0).text());

            }
            if($(tr).find('td').eq(1).text()=='b'){

                    data.b.push($(tr).find('td').eq(0).text());

            }


        });
        var HTML='';
       // alert(JSON.stringify(data))
        // if both have equal counts
        $.each(data.a,function(idx,val){  
            HTML+='<tr><td>'+data.a[idx]+'</td><td>'+data.b[idx]+'</td></tr>';
        });
       // alert(HTML);
        $('#reqtable').append(HTML);
    });
```

You might need to change this code based on requirement but it will give you an idea to work on

Check **[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzzp5/4/)** also.

Comment: What if the first table is not there and the data is coming from the back end ?

Comment: That would be more easy. in that case we don't need to generate 'var data={'a':[],'b':[]}' , it will come from server in same fashion.

Comment: how do i write the html for that ?